# Using a controller to handle returning customized css & javascript files with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, view, controller

I'm working on a php/codeigniter project and I'm thinking about creating a controller specifically to handle returning customized css & javascript files.

In previous projects I've included external CSS & JS files in the headers of my view files but they've essentially had to be static since they were just sent as regular assets by the server. For my next project I'm thinking about using a controller and essentially making my CSS/Javascript files 'views' that are loaded by the controller.

What do you guys think? Is this a good approach? Is there a generally accepted better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using a controller for your js/css, you have the overhead of loading a ton of unnecessary stuff for every request for the file. The security class, the input class, the router, exceptions, etc.

You don't need any of this for what *should* be static content. You don't want the files to be dynamic either (changing per request) because this will affect the browser cache. Either the file will get cached in the state it was loaded, or you will lose the benefit of the browser cache.

Your best bet is to combine the files, minimize them, and write the content to a static file, but then they aren't dynamic. However, they probably shouldn't be.

Another thing you can do is to use a php file to combine the static files and reference it in your `<link>` tag (screen.php). Simple CSS example:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/css');
$files = array(
    'css/reset.css',
    'css/screen.css',
    'css/typography.css',
);
foreach ($files as $file)
{
    readfile($file);
}
```

Either way, you should update the file name, perhaps with a query string, in order to avoid the old cached file being served. Example: `/screen.css?version=2`

I do use `$this->load->view()` sometimes for dynamic js, but only for inline script tags (dynamic WYSIWYG configuration for example). This allows you to pass variables to the "view" file as well as avoid cache issues.

My point of view is that it's not worth firing up CI and all the related dependencies just to serve what *should* be static content.

Comment: good point about the excess overhead. I really want to use this for situations like javascript files with a certain variable that I would like to assign on page load. But I don't think it's worth all the excess overhead and I do think I will run into plenty of problems with browser's caching my files.

Comment: If you just need a few dynamic js variables, why not assign them in an inline `<script>` tag in the `<head>`, before you've loaded the other js?

Comment: Thanks for talking me out of this :)

Comment: Although it's quite heavy, not related to dynamic values, and I personally don't like it, you might want to check out [Carabiner](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Carabiner/).

Comment: Thanks for the tip with Carabiner. It looks interesting how it minifies javascript and css files and then caches them. Based off the fact that it caches minified javascript/css, I would think it would be a performance booster? Is there any reason why you think it might be detrimental for me to use this library in my project?

Comment: I've tried it before and thought it was a bit overdone, and didn't like how it doesn't buffer the output, but rather `echo`s everything when you call the libraries methods. I got halfway through replacing all the `echo`s with `return`s and decided "to hell with it" - wrote my own. It might be worth checking out, I just can't personally endorse it and I don't know if it's maintained. For simple projects, I'd say it's overkill.

Comment: ah it echo's everything huh? That must mean the library's methods were intended to be called directly from within a view?

Comment: I have a follow up question for you concerning this: What if I set a far-future expires header for each css/js/image I return with my controller class? Wouldn't this solve the problem of increased overhead by having user's browsers cache css/js/images indefinitely and only requiring a one-time loading of this class to return dynamic css?

Comment: @CaseyFlynn: I tried to open chat again but it didn't auto-post the link. Try [this link](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1230/discussion-between-wesley-murch-and-casey-flynn) and see what happens or try and see if you can start a new chat session. I'm still not sure how the chat works and I don't know if I can /invite anyone.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there's an "official" way of doing that, I usualy split a page into different views, one of which is the page head.
If you do something like

```
class mycontroller extends CI_Controller {

function index()
{
   $data['css'] = 'style1.css';
   $data['js'] = 'custom.js';
   $this->load->view('head',$data);
   $this->load->view('body');
   $this->load->view('foot')  // where I close the </html> tag, for example
}

}
```

You can pass whatever value and, in your **view**, just load what is passed by the controller

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
<?php echo link_tag(base_url().'css/'.$css);?>
<script type="text/css" src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/<?php echo $js;?>"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: I'm actually already doing this. The problem I'm looking to overcome is that any external stylesheets or javascript files you link to in your header can't be customized for different scenarios like a view

Answer (score 1):

Something I've done before is I have a standard list of "always used" css/js files then each controller can include their own specific ones.  Within the controller I set an array of "includes" for js/css then the header view checks for the array and implodes it.  This way all the needed js/css files are specified in the `head` tag.

Example from controller:

```
$data['includes']['js'] = array('<script type="text/javascript" src="' . base_url() . 'assets/js/script.js"></script>');
```

Example from view:

```
if(isset($includes['js'])) echo implode("\n", $includes['js']) . "\n";
```