# How to dynamically control paths in static CSS files with MVC code igniter project

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter, relative-path, absolute-path

I'm creating a website/codeigniter-project that uses views which link to external CSS files.

Everywhere throughout my project/web-page's views I can control the URL paths of images, links, etc by constructing them from the 'base_url' setting variable. I don't have any control over static, linked external CSS files. This means that whenever my base URL path changes for my site I have to go through my CSS files and do global search/replaces to update all my paths.

To solve this I thought about creating a controller just to load CSS/JavaScript files and treating the actual files like views with hooks but I was talked out of this by @WesleyMurch in this question:

[Using a controller to handle returning customized css & javascript files with codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613376/using-a-controller-to-handle-returning-customized-css-javascript-files-with-cod)

How can I dynamically assign base-paths to my css assets so I don't have to do global search and replaces every time I update the base path of my site?

Comment: The base_path() can be autoddetermined or defined in config, why the search and replace? That's the meaning of that funcion, to avoid hardcoding links...I remember your previous question, and I still think you're overcomplicating something so easy...

Comment: I have no control over my external-linked js and css files. I can't load base_path() as a hook in those file when they are returned from the server. They're static assets.

Comment: Ok, so there's a big change I still don't get what you mean (now and in the previous question) ;)

Comment: Essentially I have a static css file with a lot of background-images specified with absolute paths. Everywhere else in my codeigniter project I'm using the base_url variable to construct my path's dynamically, but when my view links to an external css file I can't dynamically construct any paths specified in that css file. I'm looking for some sort of solution so that I don't have to hard code path's in my css files

Comment: @Casey: Does this explain what you want?: Site A needs `body{background:url(/assets/siteA/bg.png)}`, but site B needs `body{background:url(/assets/siteB/bg.png)}`? The image files all have the same exact file name, but a different path? You're talking about the ["microsite" stuff from your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6615799/advice-on-creating-codeigniter-app-to-serve-custom-microsites) right, not new, separate installations? You aren't using full URLs in your CSS correct, just /absolute/paths/ ? You should clarify "whenever my base url path changes for my site"

Comment: Ok...but, let me ask you, why the url changes? If you put them, say, outside 'application' folder, they will be accessible from wherever, and from whatever other concurrent installation you're using, as they're always relative paths to the index entry point.Which is always one. So, if all images and js and css are there, no need to change paths if you change base_url()

Comment: I've worked on a few projects where I've been required to move the entire website off the root of the web server and into a sub-directory. Example being: www.foo.com/ to www.foo.com/dev2011/. I stupidly had all my assets linking off the root of the server so I had to go through and change all of them.

Comment: But if you put them in the same directory of your main index.php, then the problem won't arise.

Comment: So basically a good strategy is to link all my assets relative to index.php and not the root of the web server? for instance application/assets/js/main.js rather than /application/assets/js/main.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this I use a view file containing css code with all the variables. The only change is that you should set appropriate headers for CSS

Create `function style` in your controller and set it to render appropriate view file (`style.php`). Code all your css with php code in `style.php`.

Set following headers at the start of the function:

```
header("ContentType: text/css");
header("Expires: <some far future expiration time or use mod_expires with apache>");
```

Comment: so your solution involves creating a script to return dynamic css files? I thought about using a controller/view to accomplish this with codeigniter but if you read the first response to my other question you see why this might involve a lot of excess overhead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613376/using-a-controller-to-handle-returning-customized-css-javascript-files-with-cod